# Eevee avoid light reflections in glass, but only one object?

Tags: materials, light, eevee-render-engine

Im using an area light in Blender, and it is reflecting in the glass of a certain object. Reading other answers, I tried turning specular to zero. Problem is this means it doesn't reflect off anything glossy either - I really only need to "exclude" reflections on 1 glass object.

How can I do this in Blender 2.8 eevee?